# Sharp(er) bound on a ratio between factorials

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

Let $p$, $N$ be integers and let $N > 0$. I have the ratio
$$
R(N,p)=\frac{(N+p)!}{(N-1)!}=(N+p)(N+p-1)\cdots (N+1)N.
$$
It is rather easy to prove by induction that
$$
R(N,p) \leq (p+1)!N^{p+1}.
$$
In order to prove this, though, one bounds $N^k \leq N^{k+1}$ which does not appear to be tight. For example
$$
R(N,1)=(N+1)N = N^2+N\leq 2N^2.
$$
I am looking for a tighter bound, possibly of the form
$$
R(N,p)\leq C(p)N^{p+1}.
$$
Is it possible to obtain one?

Comment: $R(1,p)=(p+1)!1^{p+1}$ for all $p$ so I would have thought there is no tighter upper bound than $C(p)=(p+1)!$

Comment: Henry: Brilliant

Comment: If you assume that $p < \sqrt{n}$ then you can get something like $e*N^{p+1}$. To do this just use inequality $1+ x < e^{2x}$ for x in [0,1] That is $x= k/N$ for each factor of the form $(1+\frac{k}{N})$